# получить hash файла

Tags: php

Вообще такая ситуация. 
Подключаюсь к удаленному фтп. захожу в директорию и получаю список всех файлов.
Лезу по локалке, получаю массив с файлами которые есть
Сравниваю их, и которых нет загружаю.
Но есть файлы которые обновились, их тоже нужно загрузить
Я делаю это функцией md5_file. С получением хеша локальных файлов нет проблем. 
А вот удаленного сервера есть проблема.
Как я это все реализую.

```
 public function connect($action, $img_name = null)
{
    //подключаемся
    if (@!$conn_id) {
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($this->ftp_server);
    }
    ftp_login($conn_id, $this->ftp_user_name, $this->ftp_user_pass);

    switch ($action) {
        case 'xls':
            $this->changeDirectory($conn_id, "FE");
            $list = $this->getFileCatalog($conn_id);
            $this->loadXls($conn_id);
            break;
        case 'img':
            if (ftp_pwd($conn_id) !== '/FE/image') {
                $this->changeDirectory($conn_id, "FE");
                $this->changeDirectory($conn_id, "image");
            }
            $list = $this->getFileCatalog($conn_id);
            $images_list = $this->getListImages();

            $for_load = array_diff($list, $images_list);
            if (count($for_load) > 0) {

                $this->imageLoad($conn_id, $for_load);
            }
            break;
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}


   public function changeDirectory($conn_id, $name)
{
    if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $name)) {
        echo "Новая текущая директория: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось сменить директорию \n";
    }
}

public function getFileCatalog($conn_id)
{
    $list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
    return $list;
}

public function getListImages()
{
    $dir = '/путь/';
    return $files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
}

public function VerifyKeyFile($conn_id,$inputname, $locImage)
{
    $dir = '/путь/';
    if (md5_file($dir . $locImage) == md5_file($_FILES["$inputname"])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function loadXls($conn_id)
{
    $local_path_file = dirname(__DIR__) . $this->temp . $this->name_local_file;
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_path_file, $this->server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Успешно загрузили данные в $this->name_local_file \n";
    } else {
        echo "Проблемы с загрузкой файла \n";
    }

}

public function imageLoad($conn_id, array $img_name)
{
    foreach ($img_name as $img) {
        $local_path_file = '/путь/' . $img;
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_path_file, $img, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "Успешно загрузили изображение в $img \n";
        } else {
            echo "Проблемы с загрузкой файла \n";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP протокол не имеет команды получения md5-хеша удаленного файла. Поэтому, чтобы его получить, Вам нужно скачать файл с сервера и вычислить его хеш. Или, как вариант, хранить хеши на сервере вместе с файлами. Что-то типа такого

- readme.txt
- readme.txt.md5

Comment: да спасибо, я уже прочитал по этому поводу. Сделал иным способом, по размерам, но он может дать оплошность , хотя и с небольшой вероятностью